# help with latex syntax parsing errors

Tags: tex-core, syntax

Could anyone help to fix the syntax parsing error ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{aligned}
        \rho &= \begin{pmatrix}
            ae^{i\theta}\be^{i\phi}
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
            ae^{-i\theta}&be^{-i\phi}
        \end{pmatrix}\
        &=\begin{pmatrix}
            a^2&abe^{i(\theta-\phi)}\
            abe^{-i(\theta-\phi)}&b^2
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
    
    \rho=\begin{pmatrix}
        p&re^{i\Theta}\
        re^{-i\Theta}&1-p
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.@kevin, you seem to have no used `equation` environment or equivalents, such as `\[ \]`, `\( \)` or `$ ... $`.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. Needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`
2. `\be` undefined
3. `aligned` and `pmatrix` environment and all math content needs to be called in math mode, implemented here in display style with `\[...\]`.

Corrected MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\be{be}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
        \rho &= \begin{pmatrix}
            ae^{i\theta}\be^{i\phi}
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
            ae^{-i\theta}&be^{-i\phi}
        \end{pmatrix}\
        &=\begin{pmatrix}
            a^2&abe^{i(\theta-\phi)}\
            abe^{-i(\theta-\phi)}&b^2
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\[
    \rho=\begin{pmatrix}
        p&re^{i\Theta}\
        re^{-i\Theta}&1-p
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]